# Use Quartz.NET to monitor Mysql table and execute some stuff

Tags: c#, mysql, quartz.net

Is it possible to accomplish the following using Quartz.NET :

i have a mysql table named "VODContent" with a field "StreamAt" - datetime - is it possible  to monitor this table and 5 minutes before or after the "StreamAt" datetime value, some process (code) is executed ?

i'am avaialable for further details if needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that by doing what you asked, you are not using Quartz to its full potential.

An easier way to achieve what you want to do would be that each time you create an entry in VODContent, you also create a trigger scheduled at `StreamAt + 5` minutes. This should be done at the level of your applicative code, in the process that is adding the entry in VODContent.

The trigger you create must have a name and a group (so that you can retrieve it at a later point). In your case, I believe the name could be the Id of your VODContent line. Here is how you create such a trigger:

```
var simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("yourVODContentId", "VODContentStreamAt", startTime);
```

Then, if at some point you want to cancel the execution of your trigger (let's say for example that you remove an entry in VODContent because your user cancelled his order), you can call the UnscheduleJob on the Scheduler in order to remove your trigger:

```
_scheduler.UnscheduleJob("yourVODContentId", "VODContentStreamAt");
```

One last important thing is that your Quartz.NET instance should be configured to AdoJobStore, and not the RAMJobStore. That way, your triggers will be stored in a database, and even if the scheduler is stopped/restarted, you won't lose your scheduled triggers.

Basically, you should try to put yourself in a position where you **push** to Quartz, instead of having Quartz pull from your application.

Comment: Hi feind, i was banned from posting question , could youhel me how can i get red of this, pleasssssssse

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this is possible: 
Create one Quartz.Net Job to poll for the *VODContent* (there are [other ways then polling for other DBMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx) but this is a simple solution which works for mysql since the mysqlconnector doesn't feature event notification as far as I know). In order to create such a job, you have to implement the [IJob interface](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/) of Quartz.Net as [described here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html) and your program has to schedule it to run every n-seconds/minutes which is also described in the tutorial.

A short tutorial which shows how to connect to, read from and write to a mysql database via the [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) can [be found here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html).

How to find out if you already started a job for a specific *VODContent* depends. You could, for example, modify the specific Row and introduce a new bool value "Processed" which gets updated upon scheduling the specific job. You then have to query only for those values which are not yet processed.

Please read the parts about statefull vs. stateless jobs in Quartz.Net and be sure to understand the difference.

That job created above would then check for changes in the table and schedule a new job which in turn runs your desired process / code according to your rules using the [simple trigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_5.html) instruction as described in the tutorial.

Comment: Many thanks tobsen, i'll first take a look to the documentation then start implement a liitle bit code. once done i'll be back

Comment: Hi Tobsen, i have make some sample and it's ok but the missing part is, i wan't to write the code which checks if any element of the table is ready to proccede (in c#), i want  Quarts to do it for me somehow , i hope you undestand me

Comment: I edited the answer and added links to the mysql tutorial and connector. Try that out and post the code which doesn't work in case you get stuck.